# how mongodb views works

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using mongodb3.4 and using views https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/ with joins, the count performance is terribly SLOW, please lemme know how mongodb views works. The comparison with RDBMS will be better.  The query

```
         db.transDetails.find().count() //30 minutes+
```

takes 30+Minutes to get the total count. whereas count of all records in transactions / assets collections is lightning fast:

```
         db.transactions.find().count() //0.001 sec

           db.assets.find().count() //0.001 sec
```

Please help

The sample records is given below :

My assets collection is of 2M Records each record is of the following format :

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58e3d9d1bd8c42d00d000029"),
        "RecordReference" : "9780002193351",
        "NotificationType" : "03",
        "ProductIdentifier" : [
            {
                "ProductIDType" : "02",
                "IDValue" : "0002193353"
            },
            {
                "ProductIDType" : "15",
                "IDValue" : "9780002193351"
            },
            {
                "ProductIDType" : "03",
                "IDValue" : "9780002193351"
            }
        ],
        "Barcode" : "03",
        "ProductForm" : "BC",
        "BookFormDetail" : "02",
        "DistinctiveTitle" : "Nests, Eggs, and Nestlings",
        "Contributor" : {
            "SequenceNumber" : "1",
            "ContributorRole" : "A01",
            "PersonNameInverted" : "Harrison, Colin "
        },
        "Language" : {
            "LanguageRole" : "01",
            "LanguageCode" : "eng"
        },
        "BASICMainSubject" : "NAT000000",
        "AudienceCode" : "01",
        "ImprintName" : "Penguin (Non-Classics)",
        "Imprint" : {
            "NameCodeType" : "02",
            "NameCodeValue" : "PPITHPTHPEN"
        },
        "PublisherName" : "Penguin Group USA, Inc",
        "PublicationDate" : "19870505",
        "Measure" : [
            {
                "MeasureTypeCode" : "01",
                "Measurement" : "5.00",
                "MeasureUnitCode" : "in"
            },
            {
                "MeasureTypeCode" : "02",
                "Measurement" : "7.00",
                "MeasureUnitCode" : "in"
            },
            {
                "MeasureTypeCode" : "03",
                "Measurement" : "1.00",
                "MeasureUnitCode" : "in"
            },
            {
                "MeasureTypeCode" : "08",
                "Measurement" : "0.50",
                "MeasureUnitCode" : "lb"
            }
        ],
        "OutOfPrintDate" : "20021016",
        "SupplyDetail" : {
            "SupplierSAN" : "2825074",
            "SupplierName" : "Penguin Group USA, Inc",
            "ReturnsCodeType" : "02",
            "ReturnsCode" : "N",
            "LastDateForReturns" : "20030414",
            "AvailabilityCode" : "OP",
            "Stock" : {
                "LocationIdentifier" : {
                    "LocationIDType" : "07",
                    "IDValue" : "257-8115"
                },
                "LocationName" : "Pittston Township, PA",
                "OnHand" : "0"
            },
            "PackQuantity" : "20",
            "Price" : {
                "PriceTypeCode" : "01",
                "ClassOfTrade" : "A11",
                "DiscountCoded" : {
                    "DiscountCodeType" : "02",
                    "DiscountCode" : "A11"
                },
                "PriceAmount" : "9.95",
                "CurrencyCode" : "USD"
            }
        }
    }
```

My transaction records (30M) is of the following form:

```
       {


     "_id" : ObjectId("59b98c6b5d8b700d6c79de7a"),
"type" : "Type1",
"testing" : "Testing Nos : : : : : : : 0",
"RecordReference" : "9780002193351",
"createdDate":"XXXX",
"modifiedDate":YYYY"
 }
```

The  View transDetails of Join of Transaction and  assets

```
   {
"_id" : ObjectId("59b98c6b5d8b700d6c79de7a"),
"type" : "Type1",
"testing" : "Testing Nos : : : : : : : 0",
"RecordReference" : "9780002193351",
"createdDate":"XXXX",
"modifiedDate":YYYY",
"inventory_docs" : [
  {

        "_id" : ObjectId("58e3d9d1bd8c42d00d000029"),
        "RecordReference" : "9780002193351",
        "NotificationType" : "03",
        "ProductIdentifier" : [
            {
                "ProductIDType" : "02",
                "IDValue" : "0002193353"
            },
            {
                "ProductIDType" : "15",
                "IDValue" : "9780002193351"
            },
            {
                "ProductIDType" : "03",
                "IDValue" : "9780002193351"
            }
        ],
        "Barcode" : "03",
        "ProductForm" : "BC",
        "BookFormDetail" : "02",
        "DistinctiveTitle" : "Nests, Eggs, and Nestlings",
        "Contributor" : {
            "SequenceNumber" : "1",
            "ContributorRole" : "A01",
            "PersonNameInverted" : "Harrison, Colin "
        },
        "Language" : {
            "LanguageRole" : "01",
            "LanguageCode" : "eng"
        },
        "BASICMainSubject" : "NAT000000",
        "AudienceCode" : "01",
        "ImprintName" : "Penguin (Non-Classics)",
        "Imprint" : {
            "NameCodeType" : "02",
            "NameCodeValue" : "PPITHPTHPEN"
        },
        "PublisherName" : "Penguin Group USA, Inc",
        "PublicationDate" : "19870505",
        "Measure" : [
            {
                "MeasureTypeCode" : "01",
                "Measurement" : "5.00",
                "MeasureUnitCode" : "in"
            },
            {
                "MeasureTypeCode" : "02",
                "Measurement" : "7.00",
                "MeasureUnitCode" : "in"
            },
            {
                "MeasureTypeCode" : "03",
                "Measurement" : "1.00",
                "MeasureUnitCode" : "in"
            },
            {
                "MeasureTypeCode" : "08",
                "Measurement" : "0.50",
                "MeasureUnitCode" : "lb"
            }
        ],
        "OutOfPrintDate" : "20021016",
        "SupplyDetail" : {
            "SupplierSAN" : "2825074",
            "SupplierName" : "Penguin Group USA, Inc",
            "ReturnsCodeType" : "02",
            "ReturnsCode" : "N",
            "LastDateForReturns" : "20030414",
            "AvailabilityCode" : "OP",
            "Stock" : {
                "LocationIdentifier" : {
                    "LocationIDType" : "07",
                    "IDValue" : "257-8115"
                },
                "LocationName" : "Pittston Township, PA",
                "OnHand" : "0"
            },
            "PackQuantity" : "20",
            "Price" : {
                "PriceTypeCode" : "01",
                "ClassOfTrade" : "A11",
                "DiscountCoded" : {
                    "DiscountCodeType" : "02",
                    "DiscountCode" : "A11"
                },
                "PriceAmount" : "9.95",
                "CurrencyCode" : "USD"
            }
        }
    }

       ]
  }
```

Please help.

Regards
Kris

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Your question asks "how do views work?", but since you seem to state you are using a view then it really should be self evident in the creation. "Views" are really merely placeholders for an existing aggregation pipeline statement, pretending to be a collection. If you do something like `.find()` or `.count()`, it effectively "appends" to the defined pipeline statement and runs it, with any supplied query details. Not sure what you are expecting here or what the question actually is.

Comment: To get the count of the records in the view, your view's pipeline has to be executed. Without any filtering that's going to be _very_ slow for a big collection as all docs have to be read from disk.

Comment: I am surprised about how the find().count() in mongodb views takes such a long time, than count in mongodb  collection (just a fraction of second)

Comment: [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) of both counts may give you a better idea of what's happening  under the hood.